# How do i install OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, debian

Im trying to install OpenCV package for Python on my debian. I ran `sudo apt-get install python-opencv` and accepted it.

But when I `import cv` my application says that there is no `module named cv` :(

`import cv` was fetched from a tutorial. What is the correct syntax?

Comment: Have you tried `import cv2` ?

Comment: What version of that package have you installed? (`apt-cache policy python-opencv`, the number with stars)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't done any developments on python but try to follow this tutorials I hope you may be able to identify the reason.

[http://www.neuroforge.co.uk/index.php/getting-started-with-python-a-opencv](https://web.archive.org/web/20130620145414/http://www.neuroforge.co.uk/index.php/getting-started-with-python-a-opencv)

Answer (score 2):

The correct import is

```
import cv2
```

Also, I've been doing a lot of opencv in python this month, and found this was a great tutorial for getting started:
 http://trevorappleton.blogspot.com/2013/11/python-getting-started-with-opencv.html

Answer (score 0):

Just execute below command line after activating your virtual environment :->

```
pip install opencv-python
```

enjoy computer-vision.....

“A lot of the future of search is going to be about pictures. Computer vision technology is going to be a big deal” 
**Ben Silbermann**